# Multiple SQL ORDER BY statements take the same time to execute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two sql statements in pgsql:

```
SELECT * FROM persdata ORDER BY 1;
SELECT * FROM persdata ORDER BY 3, 2, 1;
```

Both take the same amount of time (cost) to execute. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They take the same cost presumably because the engine is running a sort on all the data.  The amount of time to sort the data is (barely) dependent on the length or number of keys.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. I thought the engine would go through the whole data colum by colum multiple times.

Comment: @StephanPillhofer . . . Not at all.  It does the sort once on all the data.